# Future builder not firing

Tags: flutter, future

I can't seem to get my future builder to update. The api response is working fine I can see it in my logs. (`model.getSuburbs`). but it doesn't seem like my my future in the FutureBuilder `suburbs` is doing anything.. Am I missing something obvious (The `onSubmit`is trigger when I enter the last number and triggers the api)

```
class PostcodePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static Route<dynamic> route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => PostcodePage(),
    );
  }

  @override
  _PostcodeScreenState createState() => _PostcodeScreenState();
}

class _PostcodeScreenState extends State<PostcodePage> {
  PostcodeViewmodel model = serviceLocator<PostcodeViewmodel>();
  Future<List<Suburb>> suburbs;
  String postCode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(children: [
          SizedBox(height: 200),
          PinEntryField(
            onSubmit: (input) => getSub(pc: input),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Suburb>>(
            future: suburbs,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active) {
                return Text('Would Like something here...');
              } else
                return Text('But always end up here...');
            },
          ),
          // (postCode != null) Text(postCode),
          SizedBox(
            height: 300,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: OnBoardingButton(
              text: 'Begin',
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Color(0xff00E6B9),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  getSub({String pc}) {
    setState(() {
      suburbs =  model.getSuburbs(country: 'au', postcode: pc);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this part of your code is correct can you post the part of your code where you make the call to the api have you double checked your awaiting all your async code correctly

Comment: the response to the api is working .. I see it in my logs

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your condition inside the builder.

This code `snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active` could be really really short depending on the suburbs future.

Please try this inside the builder.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Text('Would Like something here...');
} else {
  return Text('But always end up here...');
}
```